# How can I test if either of two files exist?

Tags: c++, while-loop

1. I am new to C++,
   I am using a while true to find a Pass.txt file.
   Once it finds it the while loop breaks and prints `"Pass.txt file FOUND"`
   This works fine
2. I then would like to see if it can find Pass.txt OR Fail.txt with a while true
   something like this `ifstream ifile("Pass.txt || Fail.txt");`
   This does not work:

```
    cout << "          ------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "              Searching for Pass or Fail file  \n";
    cout << "          ------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\n\n";
    while (true)
    {
        ifstream ifile("Pass.txt");
        //ifstream ifile("Pass.txt ||Fail.txt");
        if (ifile)
        {
            // The file exists, and is open for input
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "          ------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "                  Pass.txt FOUND      \n";
    cout << "          ------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "          ------------------------------------------\n";
```

Comment: Hint: `"x" || "y"` will always evaluate to `"x"` since it's a truthy value.

Comment: @tadman Not sure how that relates to the question … OP is using `"x || y"`.

Comment: You'll need to test if the file exists. The string alone isn't going to cut it. Try and open and if it fails, try the next file. If you have an array of potential filenames you can always spin through until one actually opens.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's even more bizarre.

Comment: I think you want this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) if your compiler implements the `c++17` 2017 standard.

Comment: You can also use [`good()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) to determine if a filehandle is "good" or...not good.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails because you’re not testing for the existence of two files. You are testing whether the *one* file with the weird name `Pass.txt || Fail.txt` exists. You need two make two separate existence checks, one for each separate file.

To do this, don’t open the file — use [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists):

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <thread>

// …

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;

    while (not fs::exists("Pass.txt")) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms); // Be gentle to the system.
    }

    while (not (fs::exists("Pass.txt") or fs::exists("Fail.txt"))) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms); // Be gentle to the system.
    }
}
```

(You can also write `!` instead of `not`, and `||` instead of `or`; but I prefer using these descriptive terms in my own code.)

We use `std::this_thread::sleep` to avoid hammering the system with a [busy loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which will spin up your CPU like crazy even though your code isn’t doing any real work.

However, note that merely testing for a file’s existence isn’t very useful. And your second loop will immediately terminate, since `"Pass.txt"` exists after the first loop (unless, by a freak coincidence, it was deleted in the nanoseconds between the two loops).